# I have a query which contains mistakes. where are they?

Tags: sql, sqlite, foreign-keys, create-table, system.data.sqlite

I want to create a table in SQlite but can't:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[Goods] 
                    (GoodId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
                    GoodName varchar(100) not null,
                    CategoryId INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId) REFERENCES Category (CategoryId),  
                    ProducerId INTEGER FOREIGN KEY (ProducerId) REFERENCES Producer (ProducerId),
                    Price REAL not null, 
                    GoodCount REAL not null)
```

here are additional tables but they are all right. I don't have problems with them:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[Category] (CategoryId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                    AUTOINCREMENT, CategoryName varchar(100) not null)

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[Producer] (ProducerId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                    AUTOINCREMENT, ProducerName varchar(100) not null)
```

Comment: What error do you get? Post the definitions of the tables: Category and Producer.

Comment: Which error do you get? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/64186286/edit) to add this important information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inline foreign keys do not take the `FOREIGN KEY` keyword.

Consider:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS[Goods] (
    GoodId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,  
    GoodName varchar(100) not null,
    CategoryId INTEGER REFERENCES Category (CategoryId),  
    ProducerId INTEGER REFERENCES Producer (ProducerId),
    Price REAL not null, 
    GoodCount REAL not null
)
```